# Replacing \ in a string (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
if(sorting != null) {

  user
   .find({})
   .sort(sorting) 
   .exec(function(err, users) {
      if(err){
          res.status(404).send({
              message: err,
              data: []
          });
      } else {
          res.status(200).send({
              message: 'OK sorted '+ sorting.replace('\', ''),//user.find({}),//obj.name,
              data: users
          });
      }
  });
}
```

I am implementing sorting for my restful API and this has to work for

http://localhost:3000/api/users?sort={"name": 1}

this kind of request.

The `sorting` variable is supposed to contain `{"name": 1}` to make the sorting work for the "name" and I declared it as `req.query.sort;`

However this gives me `{\"name\": 1}` preventing me from sorting the right value.

How can I change `{\"name\": 1}` to print specifically to `{ "name" : 1 }` ??

Comment: needs to be escaped.... `'\\'` but that is only going to replace one...

Comment: Could you give me a specific solution?

Comment: `replace(/\//g, ...)`
using regular expression as argument for replace it's possible to make "global search"(to replace all occurences) with 'g' flag

Comment: I would have thought that `sorting` would either be a json encoded string or a javascript object, and that one of `JSON.stringify` or `JSON.parse` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your line that replaces the slash needs to look like this:

```
          message: 'OK sorted '+ sorting.replace('\\', ''),//user.find({}),//obj.name
```

Comment: This still gives me `{\"name\": 1}`